# How to debug in Erlang?

Tags: debugging, erlang

When I run my broadcast server, I got the error report:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Feb-2012::16:22:29 ===
Error in process <0.757.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{mymodule1,func1,1}]}


=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Feb-2012::16:22:30 ===
Error in process <0.751.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{mymodule2, func2,[{#Port<0.2
```

Comment: There is no `ts` module in the standard library. Is it from some other library you are using?

Comment: "ts" is my own module,  I want to know one good debug method to get the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When debugging an error or crash, it is often useful to see what input and output a certain function gets. The debug utility redbug in the [eper repo](https://github.com/massemanet/eper) makes it rather easy

Examples:

```
%%% Trace a function:
1>redbug:start("lists:sort")
2>lists:sort([3,1,2]).

21:41:00 <{erlang,apply,2}> {lists,sort,[[3,1,2]]}

%%% Trace a module and also get the return value
3>redbug:start("string->return")
4>string:to_upper("foo").

21:41:10 <{erlang,apply,2}> {string,to_upper,["foo"]}
21:41:10 <{erlang,apply,2}> {string,'-to_upper/1-lc$^0/1-0-',["foo"]}
...
21:41:10 <{erlang,apply,2}> {string,to_upper,1} -> "FOO"
```

So in your code I would for example see what input mymodule1:func1 gets:

```
1>redbug:start("mymodule1:func1").
2> %% redo the call that caused the crash
```

Answer (score 3):

`function_clause` means simply that there is no definition for function `mymodule2:func2` which matches the arguments. E.g.

```
func2({X, Y}) -> ... %% only accepts a tuple of size 2 

func2([1, 2, 3])%% called with a list instead; will fail with function_clause
```

`badarg` with your function can be thrown because of wrong arguments to a built-in function: http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/function-badarg-td3645808.html

See a list of other failure reasons here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions

For debugging: 1) the latest Erlang release (R15B) should include line numbers in exception messages; 2) you can use the [debugger](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/debugger/debugger_chapter.html) which comes with Erlang.

Comment: Many people said: "Erlang is good at locating bug", but I think Ruby is better , because Ruby can give you a detail backtraces when got error